# tornado websocket closing on server-side

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a connection to websocket handler in my tornado app, and when i try to close it on server-side, i get unexpected event code which is not equal to one that i've specified in closing parameters

Handler's method code:

```
def on_message(self, message):
    # do some stuff
    self.close(code=200)
```

On client-side i expect `onclose_event.code` will be `200` but it appears to be `1006`, is there a correct way to close websocket connection 'clearly' with specified code in tornado?

Tornado version i use is 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try Tornado 4.2? Handling of close codes changed in that version, although I'm not sure if it will fix this problem or not.

From the [4.2 release notes](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v4.2.0.html#tornado-websocket): "When the other side closes a connection, we now echo the received close code back instead of sending an empty close frame."

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Upgrading tornado fixed my problem.